# Getting duplicate data while Looping through different dates to get 100 articles each day (free version-limit) from the NewsApi

Tags: python

I am trying to use NewsApi to make my raw dataset. The free version of NewsApi limits only 100 articles per request and can go as much  as 30 days old. I wrote functions to loop through each day of the 30 days period to collect total of 3000 articles (100 for each day). However it seems like lot of the articles are duplicated. I am not understanding where I went wrong, can someone help me solve this? Here is my code:

```
def last_30_days(date):                  # function to calculate last 30 days
    date_list = [date - timedelta(days=x) for x in range(30)]
    return sorted(date_list)

def from_date(x):                                           # function to calculate the from_param
    from_date=[]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        from_date.append(last_30_days(datetime.today())[i-1].date())
    return from_date

def to_date(x):                                         # function to calculate the to_param
    to_date=[]
    for i in range(len(x)):
        to_date.append(last_30_days(datetime.today())[i].date())
    return to_date
    

from_date_list = from_date(last_30_days(datetime.today()))
to_date_list = to_date(last_30_days(datetime.today()))

api_key_1 = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
url = 'http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?'

parameters_1 = {
    'q':'covid OR coronavirus OR pandemic',
    'apiKey':api_key_1,
    'language': 'en',
    'pageSize': 100,
    'page_number':1,
    'sort_by': 'publishedAt',
    'from':from_date,
    'to':to_date
}

data_1 = pd.DataFrame()

for (from_date, to_date) in zip(from_date_list, to_date_list):
    response = requests.get(url, params=parameters_1)    
    response_json = response.json()
    d1 = json_normalize(response_json['articles'])
    data_1 = data_1.append(d1)
data_1
```

Comment: would it have anything to do with the fact that news sites sometimes feature the same article in the top list for several days?

Comment: That is the reason in my parameters I sorted the articles by PublishedAt, and if it goes by date, there should only few overlapping articles was my assumption.